# scikit-image scale does not preserve channels

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to scale my colorful image as follow.
But the number of output channels are 2 instead of 3.
I should mention that, it was working correctly before, and this is happening after I recently reinstalled many packages (scikit-image version is 0.18.1).
Has anyone saw a similar problem?

```
img=io.imread(os.path.join( imagepath, fname))
print('==> ', img.shape)
scale=1000/img.shape[1]
img = rescale(img, scale)
print('==> ',  img.shape)

outputs:
==> (1444, 1444, 3)
==> (1000, 1000,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set multichannel=True as an input property. see this link for more information:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale

Comment: Thanks. It works:

img = rescale(img, scale, multichannel=True)